# Como Puedo Enviar Un Struct Por Socteks Usando Write() en C#

Tags: c#, estructuras-de-datos, socket, struct, tcp

Estoy creando un chat cliente servidor, teniendo mi servidor en C(linux) y mi cliente en C#

mi Servidor tiene un Struct el cual tiene esta forma y según el protocolo diseñado debo respetar que los datos no pasen mas alla de 512 bytes.

```
struct Trama
{
    char Uorigen[20];
    char Type[10];
    char Hora[12];
    char Mensaje[470];
};
```

el problema radica que ahora estoy diseñando un cliente en C# y he pensado que para no tener problema con los datos seria buena idea mandar tambien un Struct desde el cliente respetanto los Bytes que el Servidor soporta para asi evitar un poco la fatiga de deseralizar bytes y reacomodarlos en C (ya que es un lenguaje que no manejo mucho)

eso hice y creo que no he tenido tantos problemas en entender como funciona un struct en C# asi que implemente mi estructura en C# de la siguiente manera siempre manteniendo los 512 bytes.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Trama
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
            public byte[] username;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
            public byte[] type;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 12)]
            public byte[] hora;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 470)]
            public byte[] mensaje;
        }
```

bueno mi problema no esta tanto en este punto ya que la implemente y no habia tenido errores hasta que venia el momento de mandar esta estructura a mi Servidor que esta en C.

He visto en otros foros que debia utilizar metodos de seralización de datos osea convertir mi Struct a un  Byte[] para poder mandarlo por el Socket.

asi que lo intente implementar asi:

El evento para mandar el mensaje desde el cliente

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (cli == null)
                return;

            DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
            string hora = localDate.Hour.ToString() +":"+ localDate.Minute.ToString();

            Trama trama;
            NetworkStream flujo = cli.GetStream();


            trama.username = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.Susername);
            trama.type = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Mensaje");
            trama.hora = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hora);
            trama.mensaje = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextMessageBox.Text);

            byte[] bytesdesalida = getbytes(trama);
            flujo.Write(bytesdesalida, 0, bytesdesalida.Length);

        }
```

El Metodo que deberia obtener los bytes de mi Struct

```
public byte[] getbytes(Trama anything)
        {
            int Size = Marshal.SizeOf(anything);
            IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Size);

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(anything, buffer, false);
            byte[] StructBytes = new byte[Size];

            Marshal.Copy(buffer, StructBytes, 0, Size);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);

            return StructBytes;
        }
```

El problema viene cuando ya teniendo todos los datos y al momento de llamar al getbytes(trama) me da un error en `Marshal.StructureToPtr(anything, buffer, false);` diciendome lo siguiente:

*System.ArgumentException: 'No se pueden calcular las referencias del tipo porque la longitud de la instancia de la matriz incrustada no coincide con la longitud declarada en la presentación.'*

es en ese punto donde no entiendo ya que se supone que la funcion deberia acomdarse a los bytes que tenga mi Struct y no deberia tener problemas pero parece que asi es.

Bueno espero que se haya entendido mi problema y si existe otra solución a este problema la resivo de la manera mas grata posible. Saludos

Comment: Te hago la consulta. Si no queres pasar de 512 bytes, y teniendo en cuenta cuanto ocupa cada caracter que seria 8 bits o 1 byte. No te conviene directamente no permiter que pase esa cantidad de caracteres,?

Comment: Una Struct a diferencia de una clase es que es un Tipo de Valor y la Class es un tipo de referencia, es para modelar los datos, y es un trabajo interno de CLR como maneja la struct o class. No creo que infiera al enviar los datos.

Comment: Si yo entiendo que no son iguales, el problema radica en que el servidor que resive los datos lo resive con esa struct y segun el protocolo que he decidido implementar tengo que usar un struct, tambien he pensado en mandar un obj pero no se como lo identifique el server de C

Comment: No se cuanto tenes avanzado el servicio web, pero se te simplificaria hacerlo con Net Core y lo trabajas todo con C# lo cual levantaria bien en linux, o lo haces con WCF y lo levantas con Docker en linux.